# How to get the balance of my monero wallet remotely?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, address, balance, remote-access

I need to be able to display the balances of a bunch of Monero wallets/accounts which I've created locally, on a remote VPS.

The private keys of those accounts will remain on my local computer only.

I don't run a full node -- I'm using public RPC services instead.

How to get the balance of an account without a private key? Is there a way? A solution which would work for me could be via RPC, as well as via Monero blockchain explorers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get the balance of an account *without a private key*?

You can't.

> Is there a way?

No.

Monero is a **private** digital currency.

Comment: What's the minimum that's required to get the balance of a wallet yet? Private key?

Comment: "What's the minimum that's required to get the balance of a wallet yet?" <- the wallet private view key and access to the blockchain (so you can scan for funds sent to you). Plus spent outputs.

Comment: apart from a  wallet private **view** key, is there a different kind of private key?

Comment: "is there a different kind of private key?" Yes, the wallet private *spend* key, required for spending.

Comment: Alright. Then keeping a private view key on a server in order to be able to check balance of an address wouldn't be too insecure because the worst that could happen, if it gets stolen, is that a hacker would be able to view my balance; but nothing else -- he wouldn't be able to spend my coins. Right?

Comment: The "hacker" would be able to see your incoming transactions, which for many is considered a serious loss of privacy.

Comment: Note even a view key isn't enough to determine the "balance", as you also need to know what was spent (hence export/import spent outputs).

Comment: `which for many is considered a serious loss of privacy` --- how do you know that this is the case for many people rather than for a few?

Comment: Transaction privacy is one of the *key reasons* for using Monero.

Comment: How can you know what the percentage of people is who use Monero for transaction privacy?

Comment: Ask yourself, why someone would use a **private** digital currency and not care about their transaction *privacy*.

Comment: Because of other features that a privacy blockchain may have, and which Monero does. Hiding one's balance from others may not be the main reason.

Comment: Transaction privacy encompasses who/where you transact *and* balance. Regardless, this type of discussion is not suited StackExchange. You asked a specific question and it has been answered.

Comment: Once again: "How can you know what the percentage of people is who use Monero for transaction privacy?"

Comment: I obviously don't know the percentage of people who use Monero for transaction privacy, but given it's a **private digital currency**, the primary use case is in the definition. And once again, please, this type of discussion is not suited StackExchange. Questions and comments should stay specific to the question/answer.

Comment: `I obviously don't know the percentage of people who use Monero ...` --> this is it, man.

Comment: @Kum Please review https://monero.stackexchange.com/help, specifically "Asking" and "Our model" sections.